SH variable in QSH on IBM i
I am trying to run a shell script in QSH of IBM i. It seems there is a problem in the system translating the variables due to the curly braces used in the script. Has anybody encountered this and know any work-around?
this is the actual sh script:
JAVA_HOME="/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit"
IAS_HOME="/QIBM/ProdData/OS/OSGi/shared/lib"

export JAVA_HOME

IWS_INSTALL_ROOT="/QIBM/ProdData/OS/WebServices"

IWS_JAVA_CLASSPATH="\
${IWS_INSTALL_ROOT}/internal/lib/iwsadmin.jar:\
${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar:\
${IAS_HOME}/iasadmin.jar:\
${IAS_HOME}/roleadmin.jar:\
${IAS_HOME}/lwicommon.jar:\
/QIBM/ProdData/HTTPA/java/lib/hatmanager.jar:\
/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/jt400/lib/jt400Native.jar"

JAVA_EXT_DIRS="\
${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:\
${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib:\
/QIBM/UserData/Java400/ext:\
${IWS_INSTALL_ROOT}/internal/engines/org.apache.axis2-15/WEB-INF/lib"

IWS_JAVA_FLAGS="\
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
 -Djava.ext.dirs=${JAVA_EXT_DIRS}"

${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${IWS_JAVA_FLAGS} -classpath ${IWS_JAVA_CLASSPATH} com.ibm.systemi.iws.scripts.ScriptProcessor "$0" "$@"

when executed in command line
./setWebServiceProperties.sh -server WSERVICE1 -service myservice -userid *AUTHENTICATED   
  QzshInitVarChars: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.   
  qsh: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.                
  QzshInitVarChars: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.   
  qsh: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.                
  QzshInitVarChars: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.   
  qsh: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.                
  ./setWebServiceProperties.sh: 001-0014 Command $آJAVA_HOMEآ/bin/java not found.            
  $                                                                                          

I was expecting success in running the scripts but they fail with the error. I can confirm that the JDK_HOME installation directory exists.

[edit] the question to add a [mre].

You need to show us the script that fails or at least something pared down enough to see the error. But if you need to know what to look for, It appears that something is referencing CCSID 420 but that language pack is not available. Do you have Arabic loaded? CCSID 37 is USA English.

The other thing to look at is whether Java is installed

here's the part of of the code:
code
JAVA_HOME="/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit"
IAS_HOME="/QIBM/ProdData/OS/OSGi/shared/lib"
export JAVA_HOME
...
...
...
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${IWS_JAVA_FLAGS} -classpath ${IWS_JAVA_CLASSPATH} com.ibm.systemi.iws.scripts.ScriptProcessor "$0" "$@"
code

here's the part of of the code:
[code block]
JAVA_HOME="/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit"
IAS_HOME="/QIBM/ProdData/OS/OSGi/shared/lib"
export JAVA_HOME
...
...
...
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${IWS_JAVA_FLAGS} -classpath ${IWS_JAVA_CLASSPATH} com.ibm.systemi.iws.scripts.ScriptProcessor "$0" "$@"
[code block]

assigning my user a ccsid supported by QSH did the trick. After changing CCSID of my user to 37, execution of these IWS command line scripts now completed successfully.

There seems to be simply a CCSID mismatch.
QzshInitVarChars: 001-0072 CCSID 420 is not supported.  qsh is initialized for CCSID 37.

I found a reference stating

IBM code page 420 (CCSIDs 420 and 16804) is an EBCDIC code page with support for Arabic script and the Latin alphabet.

Clearly, the error message states that CCSID 420 isn't supported in qsh. It assumes CCSID 37 (US-English) and because curly braces are usually in language specific locations, script execution fails.
Your script looks like being system provided but probably isn't? How did you create it?
In any case, you need to make sure the script ends up being flagged with a supported CCSID, and the actual content being that very same CCSID. The system usually takes care of conversion. With some exceptions, though.
Files being created in the IFS usually have ASCII CCSIDs and -content, while objects in QSYS.LIB have EBCDIC ones. Not sure if this can be part of your problem? I have observed similar issues with system provided C headers ending up wrong in the compiler log, but the compiler accepting these "wrong" braces anyway.
You can check the system's idea of the script's CCSID with the CL command wrklnk and taking option 8.
See also the CL command cpy for possible aid in conversion and creating a file with the proper CCSID.
Important: It is completely possible to create a file with a given CCSID as file metadata, and its content using a different CCSID! You must understand that a file's CCSID is merely a flag for the file and not some guess from the OS about the actual content! The file is a "dumb" hull for the data!
